# Pointer initialization and two pointers pointing to the same address

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to better understand pointers. I have this piece of code:

```
char theString[MAX] = "All your base are belong to us";
char *i = theString;
char *j = theString;
printf("%p\n", &theString);
printf("%p\n", &i);
printf("%p\n", &j);
```

When I run my program I always get three separate addresses. I understand that memory addresses change every time I compile and are not static; but, since I've set i and j to the address of the first character in "theString", I'd assume they would be the same address?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what you want is maybe to print `printf("%p\n", i);
printf("%p\n", j);` ? By this way you get the same addresses for the three.

Comment: `i` and `j` are both variable with the same content, but they are located at different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run my program I always get three separate addresses.

You printed out the **addresses** of three different things: `i`, `j`, and `theString`. If you print the **values** of `i` and `j` you'll find that they both point to `theString`. The `&` operator *takes the address of* the variables `i` and `j` themselves.

Here are your print statements modified to show the variables both ways:

```
printf("With &:%p\tWithout &:%p\n", &theString, theString);
printf("With &:%p\tWithout &:%p\n", &i, i);
printf("With &:%p\tWithout &:%p\n", &j, j);
```

And the output is:

```
With &:0x7ffeefbfee20   Without &:0x7ffeefbfee20
With &:0x7ffeefbfee08   Without &:0x7ffeefbfee20
With &:0x7ffeefbfee00   Without &:0x7ffeefbfee20
```

That shows you that you have three distinct pointer variables that all point to the same memory location.

Answer (score 1):

`&j` and `&i` are addresses of the pointers not the object referenced by them

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)i);
printf("%p\n", (void *)&j);
```

Same as `int a = 3;` and `int b = 3;` you would not expect `&a` to be the same as `&b`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
printf("Address of theString = %p, value of theString = %s\n", (void *) theString, theString);
printf("Address of i = %p, value of i = %p\n", (void *) &i, (void *) i );
printf("Address of j = %p, value of j = %p\n", (void *) &j, (void *) j );
```

`theString`, `i`, and `j` are all separate objects in memory, so they will all have different addresses.  `i` and `j` will have the same *value*, which is the address  of `theString`.

Some notes:

- Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.  So in the first `printf` statement, you don't need the `&` operator to get the address of `theString`.  Both expressions `theString` and `&theString` will evaluate to the address of the first element of the array, but the types of the expressions will be different (`char *` vs `char (*)[MAX]`).
- The `%p` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `void *`.  This is the one place in C where you need to explicitly cast a pointer expression to `void *`.
- The types of `i` and `j` are `char *`, so the types of the *expressions* `&i` and `&j` are `char **`.

**EDIT**

I took your declarations and ran them through my own memory dump utility:

```
#include "dumper.h"

#define MAX 32

int main( void )
{
  char theString[MAX+1] = "All your base are belong to us";
  char *i = theString;
  char *j = theString;

  char *names[] = {"theString", "i", "j" };
  void *addrs[] = {theString, &i, &j};
  size_t sizes[] = { sizeof theString, sizeof i, sizeof j };

  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 3, stdout );

  return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
  theString  0x7ffee727fa90   41   6c   6c   20    All.
             0x7ffee727fa94   79   6f   75   72    your
             0x7ffee727fa98   20   62   61   73    .bas
             0x7ffee727fa9c   65   20   61   72    e.ar
             0x7ffee727faa0   65   20   62   65    e.be
             0x7ffee727faa4   6c   6f   6e   67    long
             0x7ffee727faa8   20   74   6f   20    .to.
             0x7ffee727faac   75   73   00   00    us..
             0x7ffee727fab0   00   00   00   00    ....

          i  0x7ffee727fa20   90   fa   27   e7    ..'.
             0x7ffee727fa24   fe   7f   00   00    ....

          j  0x7ffee727fa18   90   fa   27   e7    ..'.
             0x7ffee727fa1c   fe   7f   00   00    ....
```

x86 is little-endian, so multi-byte values need to be read from right to left, bottom to top.  You'll see that `i` and `j` contain the same *value* (`0x7ffee727fa90`) which is the address of the first element of `theString`.

Answer (score 0):

```
i and j are char pointers , nothing but variables in short and like every variable they have their own locations and hence, their own addresses.

These variables hold the address of theString and hence both point to the same address

When you print &i and &j , it prints out the address of i and j in memory and hence, you get different addresses. But they hold the address of the same variable

Your code prints out the address of the array theString , pointer i address and pointer j address.


char theString[MAX] = "All your base are belong to us";
char *i = theString;
char *j = theString;
printf("%p\n", &theString);
printf("%p\n", &i);
printf("%p\n", &j);
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
printf("%p\n", &theString);
```

In C, referencing the name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, So no need to use the 'address of' operator.   The compiler will complain with:

```
: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[##]’ [-Wformat=]
```

where '##' is the number of elements in the array

Answer (score 0):

Note that i and j pointing to theString which have their own memory.
That's why, they have different value.
But the value of i, j and theString will be same which pointing to character array.

```
printf("%p\n", theString);
printf("%p\n", i);
printf("%p\n", j);
```

Output:

```
0x8efeefbfee50
0x8efeefbfee50
0x8efeefbfee50
```